# How can I change the svn committer after I've already committed?

Tags: svn

We moved our svn repository to a different server, and in the hectic mess we realised we somehow managed to kill all the users and everyone was committing as 'anonymous' for a day or two!

I know how to change the commit message(`svn propedit -r 123 --revprop svn:log /path/to/repos`), but is there any way to change the actual *user* that made the commit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
svn propedit -r 123 --revprop svn:author /path/to/repos
```

Answer (score 7):

You change the user by changing the revision property svn:author instead of svn:log.

Note that you need to make sure your pre-revprop-change hook allows this.

Comment: +1 : Mention of the pre-revprop-change hook check to allow change to author.